# What is the bash syntax to create a new directory in the directory above?

Tags: linux, bash, script

I aim to make a script for mogrify.  The mogrify command will resize images in a directory and put the resized images into a directory on the same directory level, with the same name as the work directory, but with a suffix (_a).

The new directory will be moved to another collection later on.  Something like this,

```
#!/bin/bash  
mkdir ../n_a
for file in *{.JPG|.jpg}; do mogrify -path ../n_a -resize 1200x1200 -quality 96;done
```

I'm guessing ../ denotes the parent dir when working in a child directory, but I need help here.

Edit: "n" needs to be replaced with the syntax for the working directory name.
Sorry there was a typo as well third script line, should have read n not x

Edit2: This script does exactly what I need and it's silent.

```
#!/bin/bash
DEST="../${PWD##*/}_a"
mkdir -p $DEST
mogrify -path $DEST -resize 1200x1200 -quality 96 *.jpg *.JPG
```

thanks to vgoff for the correct PWD syntax and cesareriva http://www.cesareriva.com/archives/722 for showing me the DEST function.

Something else:

```
${PWD##*/}_a
```

is not caring for spaces in the directory name and the script fails.  An empty dir is created in the same dir as the images.

Found it out now, it needs quotations on the $DEST too, presumably to help mkdir create the dir with a space in the name, and mogrify to write the files to the right place, like this

```
#!/bin/bash
DEST="../${PWD##*/}_a"
mkdir -p "$DEST"
mogrify -path "$DEST" -resize 1200x1200 -quality 96 *.jpg *.JPG
```

Edit3:
Don't even need a script for this, ie

```
mkdir ../${PWD##*/}_a && mogrify -path ../${PWD##*/}_a -resize '1200x1200>' -quality 95 *{.jpg|.JPG}
```

Comment: [Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) is what I think you are looking for.  It looks like this `${PWD##*/}`  You can echo this if you are using a bash shell to see that it indeed works.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm guessing ../ denotes the parent dir when working in a child
>   directory, but I need help here.

You have guessed correct.

> "n" needs to be replaced with the syntax for the working directory
>   name.

Aha. In that case, the `pwd` command will be your friend. Populate a variable with it or use the `$PWD` variable

Comment: yes .. is correct. but "n" needs to be the syntax to get the working directory name.  Sorry I didn't make that clear.

Comment: so how would the line look with mkdir, using pwd for the current directory?

Comment: `${PWD##*/}` should be right where your `n` would be, with the _a afterwards.

Comment: ../${PWD##*/}_a yes that worked. I'm halfway there.  The mogrify hasn't worked so far in putting resized images into that ../${PWD##*/}_a directory. @vgoff I would not have found that for a long time, thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to vote up the answer if it is good. :)

Comment: i need to know if I can put ../${PWD##*/}_a into the third line. I don't think mogrify likes that. It might be more complex than what I've tried. For example, `mkdir` in the working dir, named "temp", then `mogrify` images into "temp", and then `mv temp` up a directory and rename it with ../${PWD##*/}_a

Comment: `#!/bin/bash  
mkdir 12345
mogrify -path 12345 -resize 1200x1200 -quality 96 *.jpg *.JPG
mv 12345 ../${PWD##*/}_a`
This works!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is the parent directory.

One note is that this isn't specific to bash. It's not even shell. It's part of the way filesystems work.

The filesystem has an entry in each directory for `..` and that is the parent directory. Each also has an entry for `.` representing the current directory.